# how to create multidimensional arrays in C# without knowing the size

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix

I need to understand on a practical level how to create a matrix[][] in C# without knowing the size.
And consequently also how to modify it (delete elements depending on a search key).

I have an example loop. Two random string variables. Then I am no longer able to continue....

```
private static Random random = new Random();

for (int i=0; i<unKnown; i++){
    var firstVar = RandomString(5);
    var secondVar = RandomString(20);

    //Matrix[][]
}


public static string RandomString(int length){
    const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, length)
    .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
}
```

Thank you

Comment: By matrix you mean like a 2d array, right? Arrays are a fixed size, so you don't really delete items.

Comment: a "matrix" doesn't have a concept of "deleting elements depending on a search key" - that's *not what a matrix is*; what are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: Could you provide *an example* of what you are going to have as a result? Is it an array of random strings, i.e. `{"abnd2sd", "22czaas9"}`?

Comment: Matrix elements do not have keys, they have coordinates/indices of `row` and `column`.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are fixed size. They do not adjust their size automatically. E.g. the size is defined when creating the array with

`string[] array = new string[10];`

If your array is 2 dimensional (10x10) and you delete the value at (1:1) the Array still remains 10x10 but the field at 1:1 is null now.

If you need a solution that adjusts its size you might want to look into Lists.

Otherwise, I advise you to read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/).

Answer (score 1):

It really depend on what you want to do.

If you want a 2D array of values you can use [multidimensional arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays). This supports arbitrary dimensions, but for more dimensions data sizes tend to go up and other solutions might be preferable:

```
var matrix = new double[4, 2];
```

If you want to do math you might want to use a library like [Math.Net](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/Matrix.html) with specialized matrix types:

```
var matrix = Matrix<double>.Build.Dense(4, 2);
```

If you want to do computer graphics you likely want to use a specialized library, like [system.Numerics.Matrix4x4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.matrix4x4?view=net-7.0)

```
var matrix = new Matrix4x4();
```

It is also not particularly difficult to create your own matrix class that wraps a regular array. This has the benefit that interoperability is often easier, since most framework and tools accept accept pointers or 1D arrays, while few can handle a multidimensional array. Indexing can be done like:

```
    public class MyMatrix<T> 
    {

        public int Width { get; }
        public T[] Data { get; }
        public T this[int x, int y]
        {
            get => Data[y * Width + x];
            set => Data[y * Width + x] = value;
        }
     }
```

There is also [jagged arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays), but there is no guarantee that these will be "square", so they are probably not appropriate if you want a "matrix".

In all cases you will need to loop over the matrix and check each element if you want to do any kind of replacement. Some alternatives require separate loops for width/height, while some allow for a single loop.

Comment: this is only valid if you know the size. But I am trying to figure out how to get it without knowing the size.

Comment: @iose in C# arrays are of fixed size. You can create some other data structure that allows arbitrary indices, for example `Dictionary<(int x, int y), double>`. But that is not an *array*, and if it represents a matrix it should be called a *sparse matrix*

Comment: sound's good! It's what I'm looking for! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want a matrix or an array.

Matrix would be like

```
string[,] matrix = new string[10, 10];
```

and array would be like

```
string[] array = new string[10];
```

You can access the array with `array[i]` and matrix with `matrix[i, j]`

You could also use
`List<List<string>> matrix = new List<List<string>>();` which may be more convenient to work with and can also be access with indexers. For example

```
matrix[i][j] = "bob";
matrix[i].RemoveAt(j);
```

Given the problem you have submitted maybe just a `List<string>` would work for you.

Comment: this is only valid if you know the size. But I am trying to figure out how to get it without knowing the size.

Comment: Just use a `List<string> ` then